# JNLP crashes after upgrading to Java 1.6

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I recently upgraded my Java from 1.4 to 1.6 version and weblogic 8.1 to weblogic 10.3.6 . I'm trying to deploy my JNLP using Java Webstart 1.6 and weblogic 10.3.6 env but it loads the Java console window and shuts down. Could someone explain what could be the reason here?

My Jnlp file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://nykpsr0165:18503/EAS/workflow/editor/"> <!-- URL to the site containing the jnlp application. It should match the value used on  export. Href, the name of this file -->
 <!-- changed to test security issue -->
 <offline-allowed/> 

  <!--request all permissions from the application. This does not change-->
 <security>
   <all-permissions/>
  </security>

  <!-- The name of the main class to execute. This does not change-->
  <application-desc main-class="org.eclipse.core.launcher.WebStartMain">
    <argument>-nosplash</argument>
  </application-desc>

  <resources>
    <!-- Reference to the startup.jar. This does not change -->
    <jar href="startup.jar"/>

    <!-- Reference to all the plugins and features consituting the application -->
    <!-- Here we are refering to the wrappering feature since it transitively refers to all the other plug-ins  necessary -->  
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.gef_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.jface.text_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.ui_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.ui.views_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.commands_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.draw2d_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.help_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.jface_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.text_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.ui_3.1.0.jar"/>
                <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.1.0.jar"/>


    <!-- Information usually specified in the config.ini -->
    <property 
        name="osgi.instance.area" 
        value="@user.home/Application Data"/>
    <property 
        name="osgi.configuration.area" 
        value="@user.home/Application Data"/>
    <property 
        name="osgi.clean" 
        value="true"/>        

    <!-- The id of the product to run, like found in the overview page of the product editor -->


    <property name="eam.workflow.settings.url" value="http://njwlxfprd110.:12304/EAS/workflow/settings/settings.xml"/>
  </resources>

  <!-- Indicate on a platform basis which JRE to use --> 
  <resources os="Mac">
    <j2se version="1.6" java-vm-args="-XstartOnFirstThread"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows">
    <j2se version="1.6" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="256m"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Linux">
    <j2se version="1.6" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="256m"/>
  </resources>

</jnlp>
```

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: Did you activate the java console and see what happens? Which exact java version are you using? e.g. 1.6.0_XX?